# How to make an sql join to achieve desired result?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have 2 selects which are returning:

```
SELECT_A (COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B, SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN)

SELECT_B (COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B, SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN)
```

Desired result:

```
Result  (COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B,SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN,SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN)
```

example:

`SELECT_A` result:

```
A B zxc
A B rty
```

`SELECT_B` result:

```
A B yui
A B hjk
```

desired result:

```
A B zxc null
A B rty null
A B null yui
A B null hjk
```

How to achieve this?

It's almost like union, but can I do this with a join?

**EDIT**:

Ok. So let me state my goal. I want to make query returning a hierarchical tree.
It's because LINQ2Entities is generating extra slow and unefficient sql for query with many includes for navigation properties.

So what I want to achieve first is to get the tree... somehow.

Example:

I want to achieve result as:

```
ObjectId | ChildType1Id | ChildType1Field | ChildType2Id | ChildType2Field

    1          34          asd          null        null
    1          12          xcv          null        null
    1          5           klk          null        null
    1          null        null         6           vbn
    1          null        null         7           jkh
```

I got so far 2 simple selects with left joins which return me:

```
ObjectId  | ChildType1Id | ChildType1Field
    1          34             asd
    1          12             zcv
    1          5              klk
```

and

```
ObjectId  | ChildType2Id | ChildType2Field
   1             6           vbn 
   1             7           jkh
```

What if I will have more children types?
For each childType it seems I do need to use an union. If I will have 50 columns, i need to state all those columns in UNION (because it needs the same number of columns).
Can I avoid making all those unions with something like join just to add the columns i need (next childrentype columns)?

Desired result for 3 different childrenTypes:

```
ObjectId|ChildType1Id|ChildType1Field|ChildType2Id|ChildType2Field|ChildType3Id|ChildType3Field

    1          34          asd          null        null       null         null 
    1          12          xcv          null        null       null         null
    1          5           klk          null        null       null         null
    1          null        null         6           vbn        null         null
    1          null        null         7           jkh        null         null
    1          null        null         null        null        5           iop
    1          null        null         null        null        9           klp
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a join instead of a union?

Comment: What should the output be if `SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN` and `SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN` contain the same value?

Comment: Your second sample does not match the first.  New nomenclature.  Post the source data that is supposed to produce that output.  People are trying to help and Esoteric is getting hungry.

Comment: ok, I agree it could be quite confused, let me try once more =]

Comment: Where is this 5 iop and 9 klp coming from? Also need to see the simple selects.   We are still left to guess the table structure.  What is the table structure?

Answer (score 5):

To do it as a `JOIN` is more convoluted than a `UNION` ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4590))

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.COLUMN_A, B.COLUMN_A) AS COLUMN_A,
       COALESCE(A.COLUMN_B, B.COLUMN_B) AS COLUMN_B,
       SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN,
       SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN
FROM   SELECT_A A
       FULL OUTER JOIN SELECT_B B
         ON SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN = SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN
```

Comment: you replaced my TRY..+1 for that

Comment: Small syntax error - you aren't actually aliasing your tables SELECT_A to A or SELECT_B to B.  Once you add those, it works perfectly.

Comment: @AaronD - Thanks, just spotted that as well when doing a fiddle.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the OP is looking for, but I believe this fails if the same value appears in `SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN` and `SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4592/0). Should it produce 4 rows or 3?

Comment: @RedFilter - The OP hasn't defined what should happen in that case. This gives the desired results for their example data. Quite likely in my view it is homework and the joining columns are deliberately chosen not to intersect. They can always full outer join on `1=0`

Answer (score 1):

It is a UNION.

```
SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN, NULL
    FROM SELECT_A
UNION ALL
SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, NULL, SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN
    FROM SELECT_B;
```

Comment: From the end of the question: `can I do this with a join?`

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: Why is there a requirement to use a JOIN when this produces the desired results?

Comment: Because that's what the OP stated the requirement was. Why, I have no idea, but you didn't answer the question.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: I'd argue that sometimes you have to look beyond what the OP is asking for, especially in the case of novice developers who may not be sure of what they really need.

Comment: Union is clearly the better solution for the given example. However, the question makes it plain that the OP knows about union, but wants to use a join for some reason. Certainly, some dialog about why union was rejected as a possibility is appropriate, but it's hardly fair to assume that the OP is ignorant and disregard the stated requirements. I doubt you would appreciate such answers to one of your questions, and I know I wouldn't.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName OP said *almost* like a Union.  I take that to mean could not make it work with a Union.  Not opposed to using a Union.

Answer (score 0):

```
select COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN, null
from SELECT_A
union all
select COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, null, SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN
from SELECT_B
```

Comment: From the end of the question: `can I do this with a join?`

Comment: Read my previous comment as well as the ones on Joe's answer.

Comment: @RatanSharma Read the comment threads, and the entire question. This is not a right answer.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName It does the needful..and more efficient..Instead of commenting here and there..It would have been great if you jst asked the OP why not union and stick to tht??

Comment: @Esoteric I have seen some users refers to *all* queries as "joins", I think you are taking things a bit literally.

Comment: @RedFilter So the OP must be asking about queries in general because you know some people who misuse the term join? I think you are taking your assumptions too far.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName..Did u hav your breakfast today??Just wondering ;)

Comment: @Esoteric Not really, if you observe that the columns named, e.g., `SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN` and `SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN` are not even being joined on in the example output given by the OP. I am getting more convinced by the minute that there is a nomenclature issue here. Happy to have you disagree though ;)

Comment: @RedFilter Very true. The OP doesn't seem confused about SQL operators, though. Unlikely, but it could be a poorly formed question about anti joins with a degenerate example (I see you just commented on the question along this line). As I commented on Joe's answer, my objection isn't about using union, it's about the process. "Do Y" is not an answer to the question, "I know about Y, but how do I get the same result by doing X?" And more to the point, I don't think it's fair to assume someone is really asking something starkly different from what they've written.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how what you want is a join.  This union does this:

```
select *
from ((select COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B, SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN, NULL as SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN
       from SELECT_A
      ) union all
      (select COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B, NULL as SELECT_A_JOIN_COLUMN, SELECT_B_JOIN_COLUMN
       from SELECT_B
      )
     ) t
order by 1, 2, 3, 4
```